# How would I use the word "accordance"?

Tags: rules

If it is in regard to rules/guidelines, is it

- In accordance with the rules

or

- in accordance to the rules

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You say in accordance **with** the rules. In accordance to the rules just sounds wrong to me. Even when I was typing the previous sentence, my grammar check program complained about it.

You can say

- According *to* the rules, ...

or

- In accordance *with* the rules, ...

Saying

- According with the rules, ...

just does not make sense, right? Just how saying

- In accordance to the rules, ...